# What is the default instance spec for bitbucket pipeline build instances, e.g. CPU, Ram etc, can we configure it?

Tags: build, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines, build-server

We are looking to run some builds that require require some power.

What is the equivalent clock speed for the default build instances? 
How many virtual cores and how much RAM do they have? 
Can they be configured to have a higher spec?

Answer (score 8):

[Limitations of Bitbucket Pipelines ⇒ Build limits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/limitations-of-bitbucket-pipelines-827106051.html#LimitationsofBitbucketPipelines-Buildlimits) lists only the following specs:

- 4 GB RAM
- 2h execution time
- 5 GB disk space
- 10 / 100 concurrent builds per account on the free / paid plans

You can [increase the resources allocated to your build via `size`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_size), but this will also increase the number of build minutes used.

---

Clock speed, number of cores etc. are not mentioned there, though.
The only information about CPU power that I could find is this thread in the Atlassian Community: 
[Number of CPUs available in BB pipelines](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Number-of-CPUs-available-in-BB-pipelines/qaq-p/972594)

Quotes from the link:

> The CPU specifications within Bitbucket pipelines is not a set CPU Core, Type or Speed. This is due to Bitbucket pipelines being ran using shared infrastructure.
>
> [...]
>
> ...back in August 2018 there was a infrastructure change to EC2 M5d which is listed within Amazon as 2-96 vCPUs and a CPU of Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8175M.

There's also a link to the [Amazon specs](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/ec2-instance-update-m5-instances-with-local-nvme-storage-m5d/), and there's this:

> The M5d instances are powered by Custom Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8175M series processors running at 2.5 GHz

So the CPU has 2.5 GHz, but we don't know:

- what kind of M5d instance (=how many vCPUs) Bitbucket is using
- how many other concurrent builds are running on one CPU at the same time as yours
- does allocating more resources via `size` *(see above)* also increase CPU power

Comment: Pur C++ build mostly depends on the number of CPUs and takes approximately the same time with size: 2x. I'd guess that size: 2x does not give 2x CPUs.